# Why aren't any of these answers working, when tested in console? It was on my Interview test

Tags: javascript, forms

I tested out all these answers in the console, and each one is giving me an error.  Which one is correct?

Each answer gives me an error.[image: screenshot]

I chose B, but I don't know for sure which is correct one. Also I'm a beginner javascript learner, so apologize if this question is too basic.

Comment: No question is too basic; but you need to do your part - especially if you are a beginner javascript learner. Why won't you create a project with an HTML file and a JavaScript file - and see whether it works or not. Maybe you'll answer the question yourself (it's a great feeling) - or if you have a question, bring it here!

Comment: yeah i added a screenshot of all five answers.. definitely tried it out in the console.. but all gave errors.

Comment: You may want to read the tutorial first. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Specifically, **DO NOT** use images of code. Copy the actual text from your code editor, paste it into the question, then format it as code.

Answer (score 1):

From your screenshot, `D` appears to be the correct answer:

*(this includes some code to unhide the hidden field to make it easier to verify)*

```js
function changeValue(f) {
  f.hiddenInput.value = prompt("New Value", "")
}

function toggleInput() {
  const input = document.querySelector("input[name='hiddenInput']")

  if (input.type === "text") {
    input.type = "hidden"
  } else {
    input.type = "text"
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="TestForm">
  <input type="hidden" name="hiddenInput" />
  <input type="button" value="Change Input" onClick="changeValue(this.form);" />
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" />
</form>

<button onClick="toggleInput()">Toggle Hidden Input</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't verified any of this, but at a glance here's my take:

- A won't work because `hiddenInput` isn't defined. It would work if it was quoted (`"hiddenInput"`).
- B doesn't work because `f.forms` isn't a valid reference.
- C doesn't work because it's setting the input, not the input's value.
- D should work.
- E doesn't work for the same reason as A.